# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/file (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, permissions

```
07-21 05:47:51.572: W/System.err(693): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/file(Permission denied)
```

My code:

```
    private static final String savedRecords= 
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/file";

    Log.i(tag, "try enter");
    out = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(savedRecords));
    Log.i(tag, "write?");

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

over 6000 questions about "java.io.FileNotFoundException", but nothing including "Permission denied"

why is Permission denied, when  is included in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475951/permission-denied-when-writting-into-sdcard

Comment: If you're on 4.4, read here:  http://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-sdcard-changes    Basically you can no longer read and write anywhere on the drive.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan no i am able to read & write on 4.4 but I am unable to write in Gingerbread and i am using WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Answer (score 0):

did you use USB for debugging?

note that when you use USB for debugging, external storage is disabled.

thus,make sure that your device is in "Charge Only" mode. not in "Disk Drive" mode.

Comment: not using debugging, just using run. 
target name: android 2.2
platform: 2.2
api level 8
cpu/abi: arm(armeabi)

however usb for debugging rings a bell. is it a default setting in the emulator?